# Overloading * operator compiling error in c++

Tags: c++

I have this code:

in .h file:

```
friend Vector2D operator*(float scalar, const Vector2D& v2);
```

in .cpp file

```
Vector2D Vector2D::operator*(float scalar, const Vector2D v2)
{
    return Vector2D(v2.m_x * scalar, v2.m_y * scalar);
}
```

when I try to compile it I get this error:

'Vector2D Vector2D::operator*(float, Vector2D)' must take either zero or one argument

what did I miss?!! thanks

Ok here is the full code:
 Vector2D.h

```
#ifndef VECTOR2D_H_INCLUDED
#define VECTOR2D_H_INCLUDED

#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
class Vector2D
{
public:
    Vector2D(float x = 0, float y = 0): m_x(x), m_y(y) {}
    float getX()
    {
        return m_x;
    }
    float getY()
    {
        return m_y;
    }
    void setX(float x)
    {
        m_x = x;
    }
    void setY(float y)
    {
        m_y = y;
    }
    float length() { return sqrt(m_x * m_x + m_y * m_y); }

    Vector2D operator+(const Vector2D& v2) const;
    Vector2D& operator+=(Vector2D const& a);

    Vector2D operator*(float scalar);//float*Vector2D
    friend Vector2D operator*(float scalar, const Vector2D& v2);
    Vector2D& operator*=(float scalar);

    Vector2D operator-(const Vector2D& v2) const;
    Vector2D& operator-=(Vector2D const& a);

    Vector2D operator/(float scalar);
    Vector2D& operator/=(float scalar);

    void display()
    {
        std::cout << m_x << "," << m_y << std::endl;
    }
private:
    float m_x;
    float m_y;
};
```

and

Vector2D.cpp

```
#include "Vector2D.h"

//+ operator
Vector2D Vector2D::operator+(const Vector2D& v2) const
{
     return Vector2D(m_x + v2.m_x, m_y + v2.m_y);
}

Vector2D& Vector2D::operator+=(Vector2D const& a)
{
     m_x += a.m_x;
     m_y += a.m_y;
     return *this;
}

//- operator
Vector2D Vector2D::operator-(const Vector2D& v2) const
{
    return Vector2D(m_x - v2.m_x, m_y - v2.m_y);
}

Vector2D& Vector2D::operator-=(Vector2D const& a)
{
    m_x -= a.m_x;
    m_y -= a.m_y;
    return *this;
 }

 //* operator
 Vector2D Vector2D::operator*(float scalar)
 {
    return Vector2D(m_x * scalar, m_y * scalar);
 }

 Vector2D Vector2D::operator*(float scalar, const Vector2D& v2)
{
    return Vector2D(v2.m_x * scalar, v2.m_y * scalar);
}


 Vector2D& Vector2D::operator*=(float scalar)
{
     m_x *= scalar;
     m_y *= scalar;
     return *this;
}


 // / operator
 Vector2D Vector2D::operator/(float scalar)
{
    return Vector2D(m_x / scalar, m_y / scalar);
}
Vector2D& Vector2D::operator/=(float scalar)
{
   m_x /= scalar;
   m_y /= scalar;
   return *this;
}
```

Comment: Also, `operator*` needs to be a _free function_, not a _member function_ like you're defining it.

Comment: your implementation is not matching the declaration - you miss the &. can you post more code so we can help you?

Answer (score 6):

In the `.h` file you are declaring the function as friend, however you define it as a member function in the `.cpp`. The `.cpp` declaration must look like

```
Vector2D operator*(float scalar, const Vector2D& v2) // you were also missing &
```

Also consider making `operator*` a template function (for type conversions),

```
template <typename T> 
friend Vector2D operator*(T scalar, const Vector2D& v2);
```

so you can silently accept other types of coefficients besides `float` (i.e. `int` or `double` etc)

Comment: There's no point making it a template; any numeric type can be implicitly converted to `float`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, was also thinking about using `std::complex` but otherwise yes you're right, I was overthinking it a bit :)